# For some reason when an input string is has no value, it still shows the previous input also i can't get to the next line in the textbox

Tags: c#, string, textbox

So I made this code that when key words are typed into the first text box ("TextEditor") it should give an output to another text box ("output"). So there are two moderately simple problems that I have no clue how to fix. (1) when you write one keyword in the TextEditor the proper output i shown. But when you write the other keyword that would be expected the out that was given for keyword number 1 is deleted and the output for keyword 2 is shown. It is supposed to show both keyword outputs but on separate lines. My second problem is I can't figure out how to make output (the second textbox) to have no output when there is no input in TextEditor **After** a keyword is written but then deleted.

So if I wrote: "create" output would show "Token: CREATE" but then if I wrote "Variable" after the "create" the output text would change from "Token: CREATE" to "Token: VARIABLE". I need the out put of both to be on separate lines so they don't cancel each other out. Now if I deleted whatever I had earlier, The output text would still show "Token: Variable" instead of having a blank textbox. Here is my code:

```
private void TextEditor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = TextEditor.Text;
    if (input != " ")
    {
        string[] command = { "create", "if" };
        if (input.ToLower().Contains(command[0]))
        {
            Output.Text = "Token: CREATE";

            string[] type = { "variable", "boolean" };
            if (input.ToLower().Contains(type[0]))
            {
                Output.Text = "Token: VARIABLE";
                Output.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);  //this is supposed to change to the next line but for some reason it doesnt. 

                string[] variable = { "value", "called" };
                if (input.ToLower().Contains(variable[0]))
                {
                    Output.Text = "Token: VALUE";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Output.Text = " ";
    }
```

Comment: You lack the "else" path for the 3 if conditions, if one of them doesn't hit, your code does nothing. Also, is the compare to a space (or " ") on purpose? But let me add part of the problem first until we sort out everything... AppendText() is ignored because after that you use .Text again which always sets the complete value.

Comment: @Melissa thankyou, you were right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you are doing is resetting your text variable to say either create or variable with =. You could just append += to your text variable rather then assigning it again. I just use \n to create newline, and append it to the text output. Not sure what you are writing this in I assumed wpf and it didn't seem to like the Environment.NewLine so I just got rid of it.

```
        string input = TextEditor.Text;
        if (input != " ")
        {
            string[] command = { "create", "if" };
            if (input.ToLower().Contains(command[0]))
            {
                Output.Text = "Token: CREATE";

                string[] type = { "variable", "boolean" };
                if (input.ToLower().Contains(type[0]))
                {
                    Output.Text += "\nToken: VARIABLE";
                   // Output. AppendText(Environment.NewLine);  //this is supposed to change to the next line but for some reason it doesnt. 

                    string[] variable = { "value", "called" };
                    if (input.ToLower().Contains(variable[0]))
                    {
                        Output.Text += "\nToken: VALUE";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Output.Text = " ";
        }
```